# Build a new class

Tags: c#, class

I have simple Form1.cs which includes buttons, text boxes, etc.
I would like to bulid a new class and to have the ability to call buttons and test boxes from Form1.cs

In the new class, when i type for example `textbox.` nothing appears.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: You need an instance of `Form1` in the class.

Comment: var form1=new Form1();from1.textbox.

Comment: Form in C# is just a class. In order to reference one class from another you need to create instance of the other class. Once you have this instance you can access its public members.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Form1 instance to the new class. The easiest way is to assign it at initialization. If you create the new class instance while in Form1, then use this:

In Form1:

```
NewClass nc= new NewClass(this);
```

With the new class looks like this:

```
public class NewClass
{
    Form1 fm;
    public NewClass(Form1 frm)
    {
        fm=frm;
    }

    void ChangeTextBox()
    {
         fm.YourTextBox.Text="Foo";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
Form1.textbox
```

or

```
Form frm = new Form1();
frm.TextboxName
```

Where as to get the values of one form to another form you can also send it via objects. If you create the class of the values you are taking. and assign the values to the class members.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take several steps for this.

First of all, you need to expose the controls you want to access outside the form. To do so, in designer, select each control -> right-click -> Properties -> Modifiers -> change selection to `Public`;

[image: Change control visibility.]

Afterwards, in your class, create an instance of `Form1` and access the controls you need:

```
var form = new Form1();
form.TextboxName.Text = "some text";
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong . I tried what you said , and it does not work: i created form1.cs + buttons . then i add new class, and create an instance but still, i can't use button from the form1.cs.

Answer (score 0):

create a new instance of the class \ form

```
var myForm = new Form2()
```

then use myForm then call the control from this such as

```
    myForm.TextBox1.Text = "your text here"
```